# Как сохранить данные из кастомной html формы django в модель

Tags: python-3.x, django

Делаю опросник, нужно в форме вывести все вопросы и варианты ответа к ним, после выбора нужно сохранить результаты в отдельную модель, как это можно реализовать?

**html с формой:**

```
{% extends 'poll_api/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  {{ polls.poll_name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1 class="mb-5">{{ polls.poll_name }}</h1>


<form action="{% url 'result' question_id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for question in polls.question_set.all %}
  <h2 class="mt-5 mb-5">{{ question }}</h2>
  {% for choice in question.answer_set.all %}
    <input type="{{ question.type }}" name="choice" id="{{ forloop.counter }}" value="" />
    <label for="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.text }}</label><br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Модели:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Poll(models.Model):
    poll_name = models.CharField('Название опросника', max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poll_name


class Question(models.Model):
    ONE = 'Radio'
    MULTIPLE = 'Checkbox'

    choices = (
        (ONE, 'Radio'),
        (MULTIPLE, 'Checkbox'),
    )

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField('Текст вопроса', max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField('Тип вопроса', max_length=20, choices=choices,
                            default=ONE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField('Текст ответа', max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class FillPoll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_answer',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_choice = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_choice
```

**Views:**

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from . import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Question, FillPoll, Answer, Poll
from .serializers import QuestionSerializer, FillPollSerializer, AnswerSerializer, PollSerializer
from .permisisions import IsAdminOrReadOnly
from django.views import generic

# Poll


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'poll_api/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'polls_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Poll.objects.order_by('id')


class IndexDetailView(generic.DetailView):

    model = Poll
    template_name = 'poll_api/questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'polls'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # ord = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['order'])
        return Poll.objects.all()


class Qview(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'poll_api/q.html'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'q_order'
    context_object_name = 'q'

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Question.objects.filter(poll=p)

# API


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer


class PollList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PollSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]


class PollDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.all()
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'poll_id'
    serializer_class = PollSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]


class QuestionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['poll_id'])
        return Question.objects.filter(poll=p)


class QuestionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'question_id'
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['poll_id'])
        return Question.objects.filter(poll=p)


class AnswerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['question_id'])
        return Answer.objects.filter(question=q)


class AnswerDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'answer_id'
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsAdminOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['question_id'])
        return Answer.objects.filter(question=q)


class FillPollList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FillPoll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FillPollSerializer
```

Comment: написать кастомный post метод в контроллере

Answer (score 0):

Схематично так, то есть логика такая. Осталось только подкрутить и докурить под себя.

`get` - показываешь страницу

`post` - получаешь `self.request.POST` из формы `<form method="post">` и передаешь в модель формы `SimpleAddForm`. Проверяешь на валидность `is_valid()` и редирект на нужную страницу или возвращаешь на форму показывая, что ошибка ввода данных.

**views**

```
class AddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        formOne = SimpleAddForm
        context.update({'formOne': formOne})
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = SimpleAddForm(self.request.POST)   
        if formOne.is_valid():            
            form_update = formOne.save(commit=False)
            #form_update.related_user = request.user
            form_update.save()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('app_home'))
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, **kwargs)    

    def form_invalid(self, formOne, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()        
        context.update({'formOne': formOne})
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```